# Binary Search Tree Recursive Delete

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm working on Binary Search Trees, and currently working on recursive delete method. I have a bug in my code; it deletes nodes with no children and with one-child. Problem arises when trying to delete node with two children. (Point of reference - I am replacing deleted node with smallest node in Right Subtree)

My code is:

```
//Driver
public void delete (String val){
root = delete(root, val);
}

//Recursive Delete Method   
private static StringNode delete(StringNode node, String v){
        StringNode temp;
        if(node == null){
            return null;
        }
        if(v.compareTo(node.getString()) < 0){
            node.setLeft(delete(node.getLeft(), v));
        }
        else if(v.compareTo(node.getString()) > 0){
            node.setRight(delete(node.getRight(), v));
        }
        else{
            if(node.getLeft() == null){
                node = node.getRight();
            }
            else if(node.getRight() == null){
                node = node.getLeft();
            }
            else{
                node = node.getRight();
                while(node.getLeft() != null){
                    node = node.getLeft();
                }
                node.setRight(delete(node, node.getString()));
            }
        }
        return node;
    }
```

I have debugged and see that I lose a child when re-connecting the nodes after deletion.  But I don't know how to correct in my code.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Brian, I have to implement a **delete** method that will work for nodes that have no children, one child (either left or right), and two children.

Comment: @Graham, I have to implement a **delete** method that will work for nodes that have no children, one child (either left or right), and two children. When I debugged, I find that the nodes with two children are not being processed by the **delete** method properly.  For example,       B---C---D subtree where root is C is returned by my method as D instead of B---D where B becomes the new root of subtree.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the bug. I separated the delete method into **delete** and **deleteNode** methods. Worked out.